# MVC display model properties that has value only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

alright , so my model contains more than 200 properties or fields, using Entity framework , this reflect into the database with 1 row with 200 column. when showing this model in the view, would like to show the fields or properties which has data or value only.

now i can go through each one and check if it has value or not! but i would like to know if there is a better way so i don't have to load the hall model which going to be 90% null !?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary do you really want to see 200 properties :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using reflection and for each and here a sample

```
@{
    var properties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();
}

@foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in properties){
   var value = info.GetValue(Model,null);
   if(value!=null){
       <b>@info.Name</b> <i>@value</i>
   }
}
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WaMlKR)

In the demo, i set the question value and I kept the answer property as default "null", as a result the question will be displayed and answer will not since it has null value

**EDITED**
to get the display attribute value, here what you can do

```
// to get the display Name
var da =info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),false)
            .Cast<DisplayAttribute>();
if(da.Count()>0) //to ensure that there is a [Display attribute
{
        <p>Display Name:<i>@da.First().Name</i></p>
}
```

I did modify the demo also to reflect the result

hope it will help you

Comment: thank you ! its works , but how about if i want to display the  display Name  [Display(Name = "X")] rather than displaying the real name

Comment: @H.Rashid i modified the answer to show you how to display the name

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(p => p.PropertyGetter(Model) != null)) {
    <p><b>@property.GetDisplayName()</b> <i>@(property.IsEnumerableType ? string.Join(',', property.PropertyGetter(Model)) : property.PropertyGetter(Model))</i></p>
}
```